# write a javascript multiplication function that will return two separate results

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, multiplication

As you can see from the embed below... my script is only returning one result(500).  How can I rewrite my code so that I get both results?  Thank you in advance for your advice.

```
function multiplier() {
    var number = 25;
    var multiplier20 = 20;
    if (number && multiplier20); {
        return number * multiplier20;
    }
    var multiplier1 = 1;
    if (number && multiplier1); {
        return number * multiplier1;
    }
}
multiplier();
```

EDIT:  hey guys thanks for the help.   but I figured out what the problem was... I am not supposed to be returning an object only an number.  So how do I edit this code to make it return only two numbers???

Comment: Do you want to get both results at the same time, or do you want to get different results when you call `multiplier()` multiple times? For the first one, you can return an array or an object; for the second one, you can write the function as a generator.

Comment: Return an object or array

Comment: Since number will always be 25 and multiplier20 will always be 20 then the first if condition `if ( number && multiplier20 )` will return the result.

Comment: @MaxBaldwin i can't return an object.. only a number.

Comment: @MátéSafranka hey thank you.  I found out that i cannot return it as an object... only a number.   and apparently I cannot use the function* so how do I return two numbers?  I am an extreme nube!

Comment: One function can only return one thing at a time, period. Perhaps it would be better if you posted the code where you want to *use* this function; maybe you only *think* you need to return two things at once.

Comment: @MátéSafranka: here is the exact question: "Create a function named multiplier that accepts 1 input parameter (variable) called number. Within the function, multiply number by 25 and return that result from the function."  with the above code: function multiplier() {
  var number = 25;
  return (number * 20, number * 1);
}                                                                                                                  
i get a OK: multiplier should be a function.
OK:multiplier(1) should return 25.
WRONG: multiplier(20) should return 500.

Comment: But that description clearly says you're only expected to return one number: the result of the multiplication by 25.

Comment: `function multiplier(number) { return number * 25; }` -- this is the solution to that question.

Comment: @MátéSafranka . thnks. the mult(1) should be 1=25 & mult(20) should be 500 were confusing me. I thought they were asking for two answers.

Answer (score 5):

A function can only return *one* thing. A *generator function* (`function*`) however can yield as many numbers as you want:

```
 function* multiplier() {
   yield 25 * 20;
   yield 25 * 1;
 }

 console.log(...multiplier())
```

You could also turn the results into an array easily:

```
const array = [...multiplier()];
```

*(No this is not the easiest way, but im trying to propagate some cool js :))*

Comment: I keep getting error messages about ES6... only available with a moz extension...

Comment: @democratizeTheEnterprise OMG update your browser! Seriously!

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following approach

```js
function multiplier() {
    var number = 25;
    var multiplier20 = 20;
    var res1 = 0;
    var res2 = 0;
    if (number && multiplier20); {
        res1 =  number * multiplier20;
    }
    var multiplier1 = 1;
    if (number && multiplier1); {
        res2 =  number * multiplier1;
    }
    return {res1,res2};
}
var ret = multiplier();
console.log(ret);
```

Comment: Same as above: I get error messages about about "this code only available in ES6... only available with a moz extension...

Answer (score 0):

Or alternatively....

```js
function multiplier() {
  return { result1: 25 * 20, result2: 25 * 1 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can return a string instead of 2 separate number and then, split it into two number. Something like this:

```js
function multiplier(number) {
  return number * 20 + '|' + number * 1;
}

var output = multiplier(20)
console.log(output.split('|')[0], output.split('|')[1]);
```