# JavaScript function to multiply two sets of numbers & get two number answers

Tags: javascript, function, multiplication

This is part two from yesterday [here's my original post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50336709/write-a-javascript-multiplication-function-that-will-return-two-separate-results?noredirect=1#comment87705065_50336709)

I did not get an answer to help me solve the puzzle, but I did get some feedback.  I need **REALLY SIMPLE** `js` 100 level simplicity code that will allow me to return TWO numbers  NOT AN OBJECT . That is what I was doing wrong yesterday... I was trying to return an object not a number.

The answer cannot be a function* as that answer is not acceptable.  Here is my updated code that I have today: (as you can see I am only getting one answer- but I cannot use the function* option)

```js
function multiplier() {
  var number = 25;
  return (number * 20, number * 1);
}
console.log(
  multiplier()
);
```

Please help me find the simplest and least complicated code here.

Comment: A, non-iterator, function can return a value, an array or an object. That's it. If you need to return multiple values you have to return either an array or an object and have the caller separate them (this could be done with deconstruction).

Comment: You can return an array consists of two numbers. `return [number * 20, number * 1];`

Comment: As people said on your original post, you cannot return multiple results from a function without using an object, array, ... . Returning two numbers is simply not possible.

Comment: Since you specified you cannot use an iterator function, this is not possible. Functions return a single value.

Comment: have a look at [deconstructing assignments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Parsing_an_array_returned_from_a_function), your function can just return an array but the caller can deconstruct them into several variables or constants.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an observable library like `rxjs`.

```
let rxjs = require('rxjs');

function multiply(){
    return new rxjs.Observable(function(observer){
        observer.next(25 * 20);
        observer.next(25 * 1);
        observer.complete();
    });
}

let observable = multiply();

let subscription = observable.subscribe(function(val){
    console.log(val);
})
```

Trying to scrape the barrel for what you're looking for since returning an array of values seems like a reasonable solution...